# I want to show results divided into two parts (parallel layout)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby-on-rails and I wrote code like this

```
 <% for i in 0..29 %>
      <%= @yes_word = @moeum_set.map{|w| w.word}[j-1 - (score.sort_by(&:to_i)[j-1-i]%ten)] %>
  <% end %>
```

This code show 30 of words (@yes_word) recursively in a line 
but I want to show these in parallel layout in one div ( 15 : 15 )

Like this

```
Apple Banana
Kiwi  Grape
Mango Citrus
 ...   ...
```

Above code is worked by Ajax

```
var search_word = $('#input').val().split(" ").pop();
            $.ajax({
            url : '/jadu/output_merge',
            data : {
                word_name : search_word

            },


            success : function(html) {
                $('#result').html(html);
            }
            });
```

And this is my HTML CODE containing the results

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body" id="result">
          The words that researched
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats inside `@moeum_set`?

Comment: the variable that bring data(string) from my DB like this `@moeum_set = Fan.where(:moeum => params[:word_name])`

Comment: What is `score`,`j` and `ten` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, again assuming that you have array of strings that you want to display

```
<%- @yes_word.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <%- group.each do |w| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><%= w %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Okay it looks like you are sorting your words based on some criteria that I dont understand but if you can change your code to like this than above code will work

```
@yes_word = []
<% for i in 0..29 %>
  <%= @yes_word << @moeum_set.map{|w| w.word}[j-1 - (score.sort_by(&:to_i)[j-1-i]%ten)] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Same error occurs above..."word_name" in the error is one of the variable written in my ajax code

Comment: Change your code `<%= @yes_word = @moeum_set.map{|w| w.word}[j-1 - (score.sort_by(&:to_i)[j-1-i]%ten)] %>` to `<%= @yes_word = @moeum_set.map{|w| w.word} %>` and than try again

Comment: Oh it works but shows `[Apple, Banana, ... ] (which is array) and Apple Banana(shape that I want)`

Comment: When I apply your code, for example, in `for i 0..5` loop this results shows 6sets... I want to show just one set. where is the problem?

Comment: Can you update your code so that I can understand better what you are trying to say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90100/discussion-between-zahid-and-hyung-kyu-park).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `@yes_word` array is looking like this: `%w{Apple Banana ...}`, here's the code to transform it into two column layout (using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)):

```
<% @yes_word.each_slice(2) do |word1, word2| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"><%= word1 %></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><%= word2 %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Error occurs when I use the answer `GET https://myhomepage.c9.io/home/output_merge?word_name=%EB%A7%A4%EB%AC%B4%EB%AC%B4%EB%AC%B4 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @dimakura - doesnt it needs to be `<%-` instead of `<%`